# how to slice email to make username in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created slicing in views but how to do that using rest framework in django.

```
username = email
username = username.split("@")
real_username = username[0]
```

I have done this in views, here is my serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = "all" 

class DetailSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Data 
        fields = "all"
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want to achieve with this? It is not clear what you aim to *do* with this.

Comment: i just create username from email..
example::
email = someone@mail.com
then username should be :-
username= someone

Comment: but isn't that a bit "unsafe". Say that there are two persons with email addresses `foo@gmail.com` and `foo@hotmail.com`, then only one of these can have as username `foo`, and the other is "locked out" so to speak.

Comment: Add you `serializer` code

Answer (score 1):

You can override `to_internal_value` method in your serializer class and write your custom logic there. 
You can look at it in docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage